# How to get folder name from url address

Tags: php, url

URL of my site is:

```
http://mc.net46.net/ + folderName + fileName
```

For example:

```
http://mc.net46.net/mc/file01.php
http://mc.net46.net/mx/file05.php
```

`folderName` is always  two characters long.

```
$address = 'http://mc.net46.net'.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

result: `http://mc.net46.net/mc/file01.php` - ok

```
$fname = substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
```

result: `file01.php` - ok

Two questions:

Is this the correct way to get $address and $fname ?

How to get folderName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the address looks correct to me. However, you can get the $fname and the folder name easily using [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), and [array_pop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

```
$stack = explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$fname = array_pop($stack);
$folderName = array_pop($stack);
```

**EDIT:**

Explaining how does this work: the `explode` function will split the URI into `['', 'mc', 'file01.php']` for example. Now the function `array_pop` takes out the last element (`$fname = 'file01.php'`) from the array, that means after the first call the array will be `['', 'mc']`, and repeating the same action in the second call will will take out (`$folderName = 'mc'`) as it will be the last element in the array and leave `['']`.

Comment: KraneBird, could you a bit explain, please. You have  identical functions and arguments for getting different segments - `fname` and `folderName`?

Comment: @bonaca I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's a wonderful solution.I hope it will work for me too :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this for another way to get your dynamic file names:

```
    <?php

    $fname = "http://mc.net46.net/mc/file01.php";
OR 
    $fname = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $stack = explode('/', $fname);
    $ss = end($stack);
    echo $ss;

    ?>
```

Here for `$fname` you can use this `$fname = explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
function getUriSegment($n) {
    $segs = explode("/", parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
    return count($segs)>0 && count($segs)>=($n-1)?$segs[$n] : '';
}

// if the url is http://www.example.com/foo/bar/wow

echo getUriSegment(1); //returns foo
echo getUriSegment(2); //returns bar
```

for more :- http://www.timwickstrom.com/server-side-code/php/php-get-uri-segments/

Comment: Rakesh, your solution also works, but please pay attention on samitha's stuff. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use [basename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
$fname = basename("http://mc.net46.net/mc/file01.php")

 RESULT = file01.php
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.org/BK4bm5Th)

Comment: samitha, but I don't know in advance which file is at the end or url, `file01` or `file02` or...

Comment: samitha, I saw your demo, but - when you say `$fname = ... file01.php` how do you know that `file01` is in addressbar ?